# Difference between these two DefaultListCellRenderer?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, listcellrenderer

I got this class

```
public class FooBar {
    private String foo, bar;
    public FooBar(String f, String b) { this.foo = f; this.bar = b; }
    public String getFoo() { return this.foo; }
}
```

I want to put some FooBar objects in a JComboBox, which will display value of foo var.
In order to do that without overriding toString(), i have to use a custom renderer.
What is the difference between these two DefaultListCellRenderer ?

```
public class MyCellRenderer1 extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
    {
        if(value != null && (value instanceof FooBar))
            setText(((FooBar) value).getFoo());
        else
            setText(value.toString());

        return this;
    }
}

public class MyCellRenderer2 extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
    @Override
     public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
    {
         Object item = value;

        if(item != null && item instanceof FooBar))
            item = ((FooBar)item).getFoo();     

        return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, item,
                index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
    }
}
```

Comment: You tell us. What happens when you use each in your code?

Comment: they both have same effect, it is more a theoretical question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is ... well... the code. And what they do. But seriously, the main practical difference is that the second one calls the `super` method. This method will perform basic setup operations, like setting the border and background color based on the `isSelected` flag etc.

I'd usually **always** recommend to call the `super` method to perform this setup and ensure a consistent look and feel of the list.

However, the usage pattern in the second case may be a bit confusing, due to `item` refering either to the object or to its string representation. I'd personally prefer to write it like this:

```
public class MyCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
    @Override
     public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object item,
         int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
     {
         super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, item,
             index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
         if (item != null && (item instanceof FooBar))
         {
             FooBar fooBar = (FooBar)item;
             String foo = fooBar.getFoo();
             setText(foo);
         }
         return this;
    }
}
```

But this may just be a matter of preferences.